# Convert a dictionary into a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I need to convert a dictionary into a CSV. I have the following code.

```
dict01 = {
            "A": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
            "B": [2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0]
        }

df01 = pd.DataFrame([dict01])

df01.to_csv('csv01.csv')
```

The resulting CSV looks like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ["1", "2", "3", "4"] | [2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0] |

But I need my resulting CSV to look like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 5.0 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you check that the `DataFrame` itself is correct, before attempting to create the CSV file? I think you will find it does not contain what you expect it to. There is a simple reason for this: `pd.DataFrame([dict01])` does not make sense, as you are creating a one-element list out of `dict01` and then trying to create a `DataFrame` from *that*. If you look at the examples in the documentation, you will see how this doesn't match.

Comment: Worth learning to do this without pandas (which is overkill in this scenario, and many others here on Stack Overflow). You can use native file i/o or the csv module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by removing the list on this line:

```py
df01 = pd.DataFrame([dict01])
```

So the fixed code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

dict01 = {
            "A": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
            "B": [2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0]
        }

df01 = pd.DataFrame(dict01)

df01.to_csv('csv01.csv')
```